# powershell to update mapping of managed properties sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Is there a way to update mappings of managed properties from a file, I think checking of the crawled property exists is a must but is there a function that would update mappings ? thank you

```
#$mp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $ssa   -Identity "Account"
#$prop =Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication $ssa   -Name "Basic:11"

#$mapping = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping -SearchApplication $ssa -ManagedProperty "AccountName"

#Set-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping -Identity $mapping -SearchApplication $ssa  -ManagedProperty "Account" -CrawledProperty $prop
```

This is the error I get

```
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' 
to the type 
'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Cmdlet.MappingPipeBind' required by 
parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping` you use returns an array of mapping objects. Try

```
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping -Identity $mapping[0] -SearchApplication $ssa  -ManagedProperty "Account" -CrawledProperty $prop
```

Comment: thanks but $prop is coming back null eve though the Crawled property exists any idea why that might be happening ?

Comment: maybe use `$prop =Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication $ssa   -Name "Basic:11" -Limit 1`

Comment: not it did not work i used this form but it is not accurate, it uses Like and it does not always return the id of the crawled property`$prop =Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication $ssa  | where {($_.name-like "*$nameofcrawledprop*")}`